# Why is the string matched to STRING instead of L_ID?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I have my char.g4 file:

```
grammar char;

start: pair (',' pair)*;

pair: key ':' value;

key: L_ID;

value: L_ID;

STRING
   : '"' (ESC | SAFECODEPOINT)* '"'
   ;

fragment ESC
   : '\\' (["\\/bfnrt] | UNICODE)
   ;
fragment UNICODE
   : 'u' HEX HEX HEX HEX
   ;
fragment HEX
   : [0-9a-fA-F]
   ;
fragment SAFECODEPOINT
   : ~ ["\\\u0000-\u001F]
   ;

L_ID: L_ID_PART ;

fragment L_DIGIT     : [0-9] ;
// Double quoted string escape sequence
//fragment L_STR_ESC_D : '""' | '\\"' ;
fragment L_ID_PART   :
                      [a-zA-Z] ([a-zA-Z] | L_DIGIT | '_' | '.')*                                            // Identifier part
                      | '$' '{' .*? '}'
                      | ('_' | '@' | '#' | '$') ([a-zA-Z] | L_DIGIT | '_' | '@' | ':' | '#' | '$')+     // (at least one char must follow special char)
                      | '"' .*? '"'                                                                           // Quoted identifiers
                      | '`' .*? '`'                                                                           // Quoted identifiers
                      | '\'' .*? '\''                                                                           // Quoted identifiers
                     ;
WS: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

When I attempted to parse the string name:"x" with antlr4, I observed that the value part was matched to STRING instead of L_ID. I believe "x" conforms to the L_ID expression, so why is it being matched to STRING?

I got this.

```
line 1:6 mismatched input '"x"' expecting L_ID
```

The screenshot is here.
[antlr preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH34F.jpg)

[completed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHbGF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When there are 2 (or more) lexer rules that can match the same characters, ANTLR will always pick the rule that is defined first. In your case, `"x"` can be matches by both a `STRING` and a `L_ID` rule. Since `STRING` is defined before `L_ID`, the input `"x"` will become a `STRING`.

Note that the lexer rules are not "driven" by the parser. It does not matter that a parser rules is trying to match a `L_ID`, a `STRING` token will always be produced for `"x"`.

You can fix it by doing something like this:

```
key : id;
value : id;
id : L_ID | STRING;

STRING : '"' (ESC | SAFECODEPOINT)* '"';

L_ID
 : [a-zA-Z] ([a-zA-Z] | L_DIGIT | '_' | '.')*
 | '$' '{' .*? '}'
 | ('_' | '@' | '#' | '$') ([a-zA-Z] | L_DIGIT | '_' | '@' | ':' | '#' | '$')+
 | '`' .*? '`'
 | '\'' .*? '\''
 ;
```

I.e., remove the `"..."` alternative from your `L_ID` rule and create a parser rule `id` that is either a `L_ID` or `STRING`. Now in other parser rules, don't use `L_ID` but use the newly created `id` rule.

Comment: I apologize for not providing enough details in my description, which may have given you the impression of incomplete grammar. Now, I have attached a screenshot for your reference. Please take another look. Thank you very much!
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH34F.jpg)

Comment: @Edison like I said: the grammar you posted does not result in such an error. Either do as I suggest in my answer (which I think is the cause), or update your original question with a complete grammar that _does_ produce the error you mentioned.

Comment: The question has been re-edited and a complete screenshot of the grammar has been attached.
[completed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHbGF.jpg)

Comment: Ah, right. The error says `"x"` and not `x`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Not only did it help me solve this problem, but, more importantly, it deepened my understanding of the parser. I appreciate your insights and am sincerely grateful.

Comment: You're welcome @Edison