# How to parse a PGN move with Antlr4

Tags: java, antlr4

I am trying to create a parser for a PGN file and am getting errors on the moves. If my input is `Ng4`, the output should be `(standard_move (moving_Piece N) (moving_File g) (moving_Rank 4) \n)`. This works well with the below .g4 file:

```
grammar MOVE;

standard_move: moving_Piece moving_File moving_Rank Newline;
moving_Piece: Moving_Piece ;
moving_File: Moving_File;
moving_Rank: Moving_Rank;


Moving_Piece: ('K'|'Q'|'R'|'B'|'N') ;
Moving_File: [a-h];
Moving_Rank: [1-8];
Newline: [\n]; 
WHITESPACE : ' ' -> skip ;
```

However when I include the same logic in my larger .g4 file with other PGN elements I get `line 1:0 mismatched input 'Ng' expecting Moving_Piece`

```
grammar PGN;

annotations: annotation+;
annotation  : Open_Bracket tag value Close_Bracket Newline ; 
value: String;
tag: Chars;
move_time: Move_time Newline;
move_number: Move_Number Newline;
standard_move: moving_Piece moving_File moving_Rank Newline;
moving_Piece: Moving_Piece ;
moving_File: Moving_File;
moving_Rank: Moving_Rank;


Moving_Piece: ('K'|'Q'|'R'|'B'|'N') ;
Moving_File: [a-h];
Moving_Rank: [1-8];
Move_Number: [0-9]+ '.';
Move_time: '{[%emt' .*? ']}';
Chars: [a-zA-Z]*;
String : '"' ~["]* '"';
Quote : '"';
Open_Bracket : '[' ;
Close_Bracket : ']' ;
Newline: [\n]; 
WHITESPACE : ' ' -> skip ;
```

Any help on why this is happening would be much appreciated!

Comment: Also to note, the second version above works when the input is ```N g 4``` but not when it is ```Ng4```

Comment: I didn't look at your grammar in detail, but I do see that your only lexer token is for WHITESPACE. Shouldn't you have more lexer tokens? Also, `Ng` can be seen as a tag, since tags are defined before standard move, no? Also, do you need at least two lexer modes? One for the beginning of the pgn file where tag pairs resolve, and one for when the pgn file parses the actual chess moves?

Comment: Disclaimer: I did not do a deep dive or test your grammar, and am just making some off-the-cuff observations that may or may not be relevant.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels lexer rule need not entirely consist of capitals. They only need to start with a capital.

Comment: @BartKiers: oops, thanks. That's why I didn't post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The source of your problem is an overlapping conflict in the lexer rules

```
Moving_Piece: ('K'|'Q'|'R'|'B'|'N') ;
Moving_File: [a-h];
Moving_Rank: [1-8];
Move_Number: [0-9]+ '.';
Chars: [a-zA-Z]*;
```

See [Bart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77646815/why-is-the-string-matched-to-string-instead-of-l-id) to a similar question for a detailed explanation.

The actual fix is demonstrated in the well-documented, example [PGN](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/pgn) grammar.

BTW, the [Antlr Grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) repository is a great learning resource.

Comment: You might want to include that `[a-zA-Z]*` is incorrect: lexer rules need to match at least 1 character.